# High charts queue chart updates after ajax with multiple charts in firefox

Tags: jquery, highcharts

So if you check out this js fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/a9dkU/

You can see that running from out side an ajax call the charts are able to update at roughlythe same time.

However, if I do an ajax call to update the points like in this js fiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/8JZ35/3/

the animation updates queue up and fire only after the other is done.  Has anybody ran into this before and figured out a solution?  I'm not looking to necessarily have them all update at exactly the same time, but rather for the chart redraws to be able to begin before another chart redraw finishes.  It seems like a strange behavior that 2 charts can update at the same time if fired at the same time, but I can't start the second chart update until the first finishes if I do them separately.

keep in mind I realize that `$.toJSON({obj})` would be an acceptable and better way to do the echo ajax call but it was throwing errors for me oddly and I ddidn't have time to look into them in the context I was using it so I just made the string myself.

**UPDATE**

Here is a jsfiddle that better shows what I'm talking about.  I added a delay to the ajax to better simulate a real response since the echo api is way fast.  YOu can very specifically see what I'm talking about if viewing in firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/M8pkA/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this behavior currently only occurs in Firefox.  I tracked the issue down to  firefox taking issue with multiple ajax requests to the same url.  I'm not sure if this is just how firefox is intended to handle those situations, or if its supposed to be a caching mechanism.

Basically, the answer here is to either make sure your updates don't use exactly the same url.

So if youre ajax method is `GET` you'll probably be fine as your parameters will force the url to be different.  In case you're using `POST` or somehow getting different responses from the same `GET` url, just append a parameter that contains a random value.  I ended up just appending the unix epoch time in milliseconds since I can't guarantee that 2 requests won't fire off during the same actual second.

[See This JSFIddle for working answer/example](http://jsfiddle.net/9j8ma/)

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
 var objs=[];//array for addPoint
    function doAjax(obj)
    {
        var series = obj.series[0];

      var x_val = (new Date()).getTime();
      var y_val = Math.random();

      var data = {
          json:"{\"x\": "+x_val+", \"y\": "+y_val+"}"              
        }       

        $.ajax({
            url:"/echo/json/",
            data:data,
            type:"POST"
        })
        .done(function(result){
           console.log(result);

            if(objs.length<$(".charts").length){
                objs.push(function(){series.addPoint([result.x, result.y], true, true)}); 
            }
            if(objs.length==$(".charts").length){//all data loaded 
                $.each(objs,function(i,n){
                    n();//call each addPoint
                });
                objs=[];//clear array
            }



        }); 
    }
```

and change setTimeout on redraw

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
            events: {
                load: function() {doAjax(this);},
                redraw:function(){var t=this;setTimeout(function() {doAjax(t);}, 1000);}
            }
        },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8JZ35/4/

Comment: Hi thanks for the thorough answer.  But while this answer does force them to  update all at once, it doesn't actually correct the underlying issue, but more disguises it.  Say I have 20 of these charts on a page.  I want the first one to be able to begin its redraw while say, the 14th is already redrawing, for example.  I'll update my question to reflex this more clearly.

Comment: have you tried with async:false on  $.ajax ? it work most of the time [http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7Vq/](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ7Vq/)

Comment: that forces the same condition thats already there.  If you add more than 2 charts it becomes easier to notice if you don't see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to redraw() both chart only in second call `ajax()` function,

http://jsfiddle.net/8JZ35/5/

http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Series.addPoint()

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that too forces the charts to update synchronously and the goal is to let any chart begin its update independent of what the other charts are doing/have done.

Comment: In both example you need redraw() so resulat is the same.

Comment: Yes but the redraw() functions queue up if they aren't fired at the same time, and with your method if I were to expand it to say 20 charts,  I would have to wait for all 20 to finish their ajax calls before any of them updated, its just another flavor of the approach of the other answer.  I'll add another example with more charts that shows this more obviously and with what approaches I tried in the hell I call yesterday.  Give me a minute.

Comment: update added.  Be sure to look at it in firefox to see it pretty clearly.

Comment: You mentioned about waiting for last ajax (to redraw all), but in case when you have 20 charts, and would like to have sychronised all of them, you need to wait for last, as well. In other words, if you would like to have sychronise all of them, you have to wati for all ajax and redrwa charts. Why you cannot use one ajax and get data for all charts?

Comment: I don't want to synchronise them.  I want for the first chart not to have to wait for the last one to update before it begins its next update.  Their behavior is acting synchronous and I want them to be more asynchronous.

Comment: To be honest, I read your description and I'm still not sure how it should works. I know that not sychronised, but asychronised. It is clear, but it works in this way in example from UPDATE section. Could you explain in more details?

Comment: I narrowed it down to a firefox only issue.  I actually solved it as well.  I'll post an answer and retitle the question for better search referencing when I have time.